# Problems on vector calculus

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

I have no idea about vector calculus, rather i am comfortable with abstract algebra. One of my juniors asked the following questions:

> (1) Prove that $\nabla(\frac{x}{r^2})=\frac{-2x}{r^4}$, where $\nabla$ is gradient operator.
>
> (2) Solve $\int a.(r\times \frac{d^2r}{dt^2})dt$.

I regret, if the question is not suitable for this forum.

Comment: The gradient vector is $\nabla f= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\vec{i}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\vec{j}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\vec{k}$ and $f(x,y,z)= \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+ y^2+ z^2}}$.  Do the partial derivatives!

Comment: [Abstract algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_algebra)? I think you meant  [abstract indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_index_notation).

Comment: Could you double-check in (1) which quantities are scalars, which are vectors and which are vector components, and whether $\nabla$ is meant to be a grad or div?

Comment: @J. G. I confess that i am not good at vector calculus portion, but usually i deal specifically, the linear algebra and abstract algebra.

Comment: @J.G. $r$, $x$ and $\nabla$ are scalar, vector and grad, respectively.

Comment: @gete So you're taking the grad of a vector?

Comment: Is $a$ a constant vector or a synonym for $d^2r/dt^2$? If it's the former, move $a\cdot$ outside the integral and use integration by parts; if it's the latter, the integrand vanishes.

Comment: @J.G.  yes, it is grad over a vector. And $a$ is a constant

Comment: @J.G Sorry, $r$ should be a vector quantity and $x$ is scalar.

Comment: So you're taking the grad of a scalar, then getting a scalar? That's also not feasible.